# ToastBar style - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've used a toastbar. But the text message doesnot align with icon. How can I center the text vertically with respect to icon.

Code

```
ToastBar.showErrorMessage("You are offline");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a misbehavior that needs improving. Please file an issue on that, we also need better default padding especially on hi-DPI devices.

You can customize the icon size & text padding to workaround this behavior as a workaround. Specifically targeting the following UIID's: `ToastBar` & `ToastBarMessage`.